# Does "mailing" necessarily means sending hard copy?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

> But how about collecting signatures for a popular initiative or a
> referendum, in which digital tools can play their strengths of quick
> and massive mobilisation? In contrast to e-voting, we do not have
> systematic evidence on the effects of e-collecting (Bisaz & Serdült
> 2017). Few experiences of private actors such as wecollect.ch show
> that e-collecting is promising: in several cases, they succeeded in
> collecting in shorter time a greater part of the required signatures
> for a referendum (50’000) or a popular initiative (100’000) than
> actors on the street. **In its present form, e-collecting platforms,
> on request, mail an official form which the voter has to print, sign
> by hand and then mail back (postage is covered).**
>
> - Swiss Democracy by Wolf Linder

I want to know how to sign collecting works in this paragraph. E-collecting platform mails a form to voter to fill. Is this mail a hard copy or soft copy? Because If it is hard copy why a voter need to print it? Then if it is soft copy does why does it imply a postage cost in the sentence I emphasized.

Then again is it possible to the first "mail" word to be electronic mail and the second to be real mail?

Comment: _On request_ (if the voter asks for it) they can send out a form (electronically, since the voter has to print it). The printed copy is signed and sent back by post (since the cost of postage is mentioned). So, the answer to your question is yes.

Comment: The sample text here is obviously ***badly translated*** (or just *written by someone with limited communications skills*) so you can't really read anything in to the fact that it explicitly (and rather curiously, imho) talks about ***mailing*** a "form" that the recipient has to actually ***print a hard copy of***.

Answer (score -1):

Not necessarily. Mailing can refer to soft copies, or electronic copies. For example, you can use the word "mailing" to refer to sending emails. However, "emailing" is more commonly used for this, as it helps make the distinction clearer.